# scss each loop with list - SassError: $color: XX,XX,XX is not a color

Tags: sass

I am trying to write a loop in scss that takes a list and uses the $key, $val of each loop to populate and name a @keyframes rule. Here is my code:

```
$alarmRgb: 255, 213, 0;
$infoRgb: 25, 97, 166;
$warnRgb: 240, 111, 50;
$errorRgb: 228, 35, 38;
$successRgb: 0, 149, 52;

$pulseList:(
  alarm: $alarmRgb,
  info: $infoRgb,
  warn:  $warnRgb,
  error: $errorRgb,
  success: $successRgb
);

@each $key, $val in $pulseList {
  @keyframes pulse-#{$key}  {
    0% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(unquote(#{$val}), 0.7);
    }

    70% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(unquote(#{$val}), 0);
    }

    100% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(unquote(#{$val}), 0);
    }
  }
}
```

So I created the rgb values as variables (but not the A value), then created the list using these variables, created the loop and tried to put the 3 number values into the box-shadow, rgba value. However I get the error: **SassError: $color: 255, 213, 0 is not a color**.

I removed the `unquote` method from the loop, that didn't work. I changed my variables to string values and then reapplied to unquote method, this didn't work. I am unsure what I can do to get my scss loop working with the values from my list. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working with the following amendments...

```
$alarmRgb: rgb(255, 213, 0);
$infoRgb: rgb(25, 97, 166);
$warnRgb: rgb(240, 111, 50);
$errorRgb: rgb(228, 35, 38);
$successRgb: rgb(0, 149, 52);

$pulseList:(
  alarm: $alarmRgb,
  info: $infoRgb,
  warn:  $warnRgb,
  error: $errorRgb,
  success: $successRgb
);

@each $key, $val in $pulseList {
  // pulse animation for info #{$key}
  @keyframes pulse-#{$key}  {
    0% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba($val, 0.7);
    }

    70% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba($val, 0);
    }

    100% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba($val, 0);
    }
  }
}
```